# Check setState has run before executing API call in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with a text field and a form input which accepts multiple files. OnSubmit the files are sent to Firebase Storage, which sends back a URL for each file. These URLs are then stored in a 'photosURL' array in the form object, which is then posted to MongoDB.

The problem is, every time I post the form object data to Mongo, the photos array is empty, despite the console log showing it to be populated before I call the post-to-Mongo code. This leads me to think the post-to-Mongo code is using the form object value before it has been populated with the photo URLs.

The question is, how do I check that the photo array has been populated before I run the code to push the data to MongoDB? I'm already using a Promise.all to in theory wait for all the files to be sent and the URLs returned, but I can't work out why else the photoURLs array is empty every time data is sent to Mongo.

Here's the code:

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
    userId: '',
    post: '',
    createdAt: createdAt,
    photoURLs: [],
})

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    newPost ? postData(form) : ...
}

// SEND FILE TO FIREBASE AND GET BACK THE URL
async function handleUpload(file) {

    const storageRef = useStorage.ref("PostImages");
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(`${nanoid()}`);

    return fileRef.put(file).then(() => {
        return fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
            photoArray.push(url);
            setForm(prevState => ({ ...prevState, photos: photoArray }))
        });
    });
}

// POST FUNCTION
const postData = async (form) => {

    setLoading(true)
    let thisFileArray = fileInput.current.files;
    const uploadTasks = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < thisFileArray.length; i++) {
        uploadTasks.push(handleUpload(thisFileArray[i]));
    }
    Promise.all(uploadTasks).then(() => {
        axios.post('/api/posts', form)
        .then(response => {
            ...
        })
        .catch(error => {
            ...
        })
    })
}
```

Can anyone see what's going wrong, please?

EDIT: This is a consolel log of the form object, called before the axios.post code (it's showing the photosURL as populated):

```
createdAt: 1630072305502
photos: 
    0: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
    1: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
post: "sample text"
userId: "1iNGV..."
```

Comment: where is`photoArray` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are running into a timing issue.
Don't forget that React state updates are asynchronous, as described [here](https://sentry.io/answers/forget-set-state-is-async/#the-problem).
I suggest to pass your URLs directly instead of going through your component's state:

```
async function handleUpload(file) {
    const storageRef = useStorage.ref("PostImages");
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(`${nanoid()}`);
    await fileRef.put(file);
    const url = await fileRef.getDownloadURL();
    return url; // Send back the download URL
}

const postData = async (form) => {
    setLoading(true);
    let thisFileArray = fileInput.current.files;
    const uploadTasks = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < thisFileArray.length; i++) {
        uploadTasks.push(handleUpload(thisFileArray[i]));
    }
    const photos = await Promise.all(uploadTasks); // Get all URLs here
    await axios.post('/api/posts', {...form, photos}); // Send URLs to your server
    setLoading(false);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, sincere thanks Louis. This worked perfectly. I'm well aware of the synchronous nature of React's state updates, having had many 'issues' with it in the past. I had just thought Promise.all was taking care of this, but evidently not. Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, You want to upload files first and when you get your urls array populated then only you want to call `postData` function?

If that's the case, then you can use `useEffect` to detect the urls change.

```
useEffect(() => {
// Here you call your postData function. 
postData();

}, [form.photoURLs])
```

What this will do is, Whenever your `form.photoURLs` gets populated this useEffect will run and will make the request to the server with proper data.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, I do understand what you're saying. It's just that I was trying to do it without a useEffect as I  really want to call postData() on form submit. It's not really practical to call it when the form.photoURLs change in case the user hasn't yet filled out the rest of the form.   I suppose the simple question is, why is my photoURLs array empty every time I send the data to Mongo, despite console logs telling me it has been populated.

Comment: Did you check the network tab? Your request payload sending empty array?

Comment: Yes it is, and I don't know why. Just the photoURLs array is empty. I have update the question with an example console.log

Comment: Just for testing can you wrap your axios.post request in setTimeout of 1 second and and see how it works, then we can debug further.\

Comment: It's still empty in Mongo. I really thought that would work. Even tried two seconds lol

Comment: Payload empty too

Comment: I guess you promise is getting resolve earlier